# Make ringer volume differ from music volume and vice versa

Tags: lumia, volume

I am using a Lumia 710 and I like to listen to my music at a low volume (10-15) The problem is the same volume controls are used by the ringer which is not highly audible. Is there a setting or an app to separate the volume controls for ringer and music?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently this is not supported
http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1549681-control-ringtone-and-media-volume-separately